# Regular expression doesn't work in camel route

Tags: regex, apache-camel

I have several routes configured by xmls. 
So I need to harvest only *.xml or *.XML or even *.xMl files,
but not *.XMLxml files.
so when I put the following regular expression:

```
....&amp;include=(.*.+\.(?i)[x](?i)[m](?i)[l]$)......
```

into route configuration it doesn't work, but regexp works in code as well as in some online validators.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
include=.+\.xml$
```

with case insensitivity turned on if needed. Your example seems overly complex.

Alternatively,

```
include=.+\.[Xx][Mm][Ll]$
```

should work too.

Also, be aware of all levels of escaping. You may need to escape the backslash, like so: `\\`. You may also need to encode some elements.

Comment: No, this doesn't work for me. 
I also tried to escape backslash, but it did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Why not .*\.[xX][mM][lL]? (I'm simplifying here, but I think the idea is clear...)